# Bigbluebutton desktop sharing issue in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, bigbluebutton

I am working in bigbluebutton 0.8.1. I had setup the development environment in my local(ubuntu 10.04)  and desktop sharing is working fine.

Later i created new bbb-desktop-applet jar, using the url
https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/081DevelopingBigBlueButton#Developing_Deskshare.
And then moved the newly created jar to this location var/www/bigbluebutton/client in ubuntu machine and then restarted the server.  I can able to create and join the room, but not able to share my desktop, getting below error. Already I added the url in exception site list in java control panel but still it is not working. Guide me here please.[image]

Comment: Help me out from this issue.

Comment: change the Java security settings http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~crypto/fixjava.html

Comment: Thanks man.i will try and let you know.

Comment: i tried both solution.but still issue exists.

Comment: just to make sure, the exception you added was for the same address as in the error message?

Comment: yeah we added the same link bart.